# Linux kernel build : Perform "make localmodconfig" non-interactive way

Tags: linux, build, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I'd like to run 'make localmodconfig' in an non-interactive way. While trying

> yes " " | make localmodconfig

gave below error:

```
Console input/output is redirected. Run 'make oldconfig' to update configuration.

make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/Makefile:45: localmodconfig] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:547: localmodconfig] Error 2
```

I prefer localmodconfig instead of olddefconfig because older kernel has 3000+ modules and uses only 30 of them. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: thanks, I'll use this method. If possible move it as answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having some old `.config` in your kernel source directory, you can do:

```
$ make olddefconfig
$ make localmodconfig
```

- First command will use old `.config` and will answer default values to all new options, making `.config` applicable to your new kernel
- Second command will disable all modules that are not currently loaded on your machine, in `.config` (using `lsmod` output)
- As first command already made `.config` valid for your new kernel, second command won't ask you any questions about new options, so you can avoid using `yes` tool.

Comment: This still asks me some questions :(.

Comment: @pevik Can you please elaborate? First command or second one? Which kind of questions? is there some public git repo out there where that issue can be reproduced (or is it possible for you to share such a repo)? Can you show the output of your `lsmod` and `.config` you use as a reference for `make olddefconfig`? Which kernel version that `.config` is for, and which kernel version you're trying to build? Basically in order to help you I'll need some [minimal reproducible example](http://sscce.org/) from your side, for the issue you mentioned, which will cover my questions above.

Comment: haven't found why, I might add MRE later. It's *sometimes* when using openSUSE config (from openSUSE kernel packaging https://kernel.opensuse.org/cgit/kernel/, which has some SUSE patches) on next tree.